# how do i get room database id from the list that shows that id Entry?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

So i have a recycler view that shows entries from my room database,
in my application i implemented on click listener on my recycler view so when an element is clicked it launches an activity.

```
 override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(this, PlaceViewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("index", position)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

and in that activity i use fetch data by id Dao function and then display the data on text views.

```
val placesDao = (application as PlaceApplication).db.placesDao()

        val index = intent.getIntExtra("index", 0)

        showData((index + 1), placesDao)
```

right know I'm using put extra and adding 1 to the position index then put the index inside
dao fetch by id function, now i would like to know if there's a way to get room database id
when i click on my recycler view element, so i can directly pass it into my dao function instead of getting index and adding 1 to it.

Comment: don't you get the ID itself when clicking in onItemClick?

Comment: no, it's actually the array list index that populates the recycle view , it get data from "fetch all entries " dao function.

Comment: you can modify onItemClick to send ID itself. As you've arraylist in recyclerview. It hold's the Id as well which you require.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion i'm looking into it and see if i can get it to pass the id

Comment: alright man i figured it out , i simply passed my id as a parameter in onItemClick function 

`override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            val item = items[position]
            val id = item.id
            
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position, id)
            }`

and then i was able to retrieve it in my main activity

Answer (score 0):

the way i was to get id was passing it into my onItemClick function

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            val item = items[position]
            val id = item.id
            
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position, id)
            }
}
```